# Loading Remote images in TableView while keeping sizes intact

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to show a table view where each cell will just contain one image. Images are loaded from respective URLs and there is no restriction on the size of the image.

I want to show the image in each cell with their proper sizes - that is maintain the aspect ratio. I am guessing this would entail having dynamic heights for each cell. But I am not sure and can't find a resource which explains how to achieve this.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the image height and width dynamically first and set the same hieght and width to your table view cells.

I have not added table view but just some code will help you see how you can show two different images with their original height and width and adding the same to a view.

```
 NSURL *imageURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.macrumors.com/article-new/2014/12/applelogo.png"];
    NSData *imageData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL1];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];

    UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image1];
    //CGFloat height = imageView.frame.size.height;
    //CGFloat width = imageView.frame.size.width;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView1];

    //sample urls :- http://pre01.deviantart.net/e711/th/pre/f/2013/179/2/c/ios_7_icons__updated__by_iynque-d69mme1.png

    NSURL *imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/position-relative/social-2/128/ios-icon.png"];
    NSData *imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];

    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image2];
    CGFloat height = imageView2.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width = imageView2.frame.size.width;
    imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, width, height);
    NSLog(@"height :- %f, Width :- %f ",height, width);

    [self.view addSubview:imageView2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you are loading the images asynchronously, as answered here: [Loading images for UITableViewCell from URL (need to load them asynchronously)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750426/loading-images-for-uitableviewcell-from-url-need-to-load-them-asynchronously?rq=1)

You'll need a custom cell or prototype cell with a `UIImageView` set to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.  In the cell, set the constraints how you want them: that is, if you want the image to be the full width of the screen, set leading and trailing constraints, and constrain to the top and bottom.

Then, set your table view to use dynamic sizing:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0; //or some reasonable first approximation
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```